# how to retrieve row data with multi rows form another table with no relation laravel 8

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-8

I am working with Laravel 8 and i have these database tables structure

users table structure

> id and name

articles table structure

> id, title,content, and authors

the models are

> Article and User

I store the users ids in authors field in articles table as following format

> 1,6,9 for example

but unfortunately I stucked how I can  retrieve all articles row data with it's authors id and name and get confused how to write the query

Comment: can you share code details? i guess then it will take few minutes to resolve the problem

Comment: i don't write the query because i don't know how to write it ^_^

Comment: please write you laravel code.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have this in create articles migration.

```
$table->bigInteger('authors');
$table->foreign('authors')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Second you need to have this code in User Model.

```
public function articles() {
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'authors' );
}
```

and then access user's articles like this.

```
$user->articles
```

Comment: if you mean to create new table for authors i already have users table and the author id is the same user id

Comment: no no. not any table. i mean to say authors must be foreign key and i wrote code to do that in Laravel migrations.